# What is the correct formula for the covariance matrix?

Tags: principal-component-analysis

I am solving about **principal component analysis** (PCA) and I stumbled upon a place where I need to calculate the covariance matrix, I am seeing varieties of formula. Here are some that I have found:

---

[image: Theses are 2 formulas]

---

The $n$ or $n-1$ is confusing me. What is the correct formula?

[This source](https://www.gatevidyalay.com/principal-component-analysis-dimension-reduction) solves using $n$, whereas [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCqCcC2o16U&t=214s) solves using $n - 1$ in the denominator.

Comment: the first is an unbiased estimate, the second is biased. that is essentially the difference between both formulas. both are correct.

Answer (score 1):

There is no correct or incorrect here.

The difference, $n-1$, is called the [Bessel's correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_correction)

It corrects the bias in the estimation we do about the variance (we do not know the true population variance).

- In most statistical textbooks, they use this correction when explaining covariance (especially when the focus is on applying the formula instead of understanding the underlying theory).
- Most packages (e.g. Matlab, NumPy for Python) use this correction in their covariance function.

So I don't really see a place in statistics for the biased formula.
When applying covariance, and thus also when doing PCA, I would go for the $n-1$ variant.

But to stress again: it's not a question of correct or incorrect. In probability theory, when calculating the variance of a discrete random variable, you don't want to apply the correction. So be careful to always go for on or the other whenever you are dealing with variance.